# Can't use oracle.DataAccess.Client on .net 3.5 Framework

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, odac

The problem is that i created project on .net framwork using oracle.dataaccess.client of ODTwithODAC112030 that works with .net 4.0 or latest and client's machine has .net 3.5. I can't install .net 4 on clients machine. Is there ODP for .net 3.5?? How can i solve this problem??

Comment: ODP works with .Net 4.0 or later see the post 
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965900/parser-error-message-failed-to-generate-code-exception-of-type-system-data-de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that instalation You should have Oracle Data Provider for .Net 2.0.
Use that one. It works with .Net 3.5.

Comment: How do you choose the data provider inside Visual Studio?

Comment: @Jaanus by referencing specific dll

Comment: Well I have a plain library(DLL) project. I add ADO.NET model to the project, which generates edmx model form me. At what point should I add/change the reference, and what is the reference name?

Comment: @Jaanus are You using Oracle DB?

Comment: Yes, I am using Oracle DB. I think ADO.NET isn't supported for 3.5 now, not sure.